# Output Buffering or Re-arrange the code

Tags: php

I'm developing a small website using PHP, and during my research i saw many projects which write `ob_start` at the top of the page before the `DOCTYPE` just because they need to redirect the user mid-page in case of an error (without triggering the "Headers already sent" error).

Now i'm a bit confused because i never knew that `ob_start` can be used that way (i mean buffer an entire page), I always wrote my codes like this:

```
<?php
    // First: Logic stuff and Validation (with redirects on error)

    // Last: HTML markup or include 'header.php';
?>
```

And i never had problems with the headers. So which is better? should i also use `ob_start` instead of splitting the codes?

Comment: ob_start is a *poor* solution to 'headers already sent'. look at the related questions on the right

Comment: This is a topic which will likely get some different opinions, however I would venture to guess that most experienced developers would tell you to only use output buffering when absolutely necessary.  Really, you should focus on separating the logic of your code from the displays aspects of it.  Determine before rendering the page what sort of headers you need to send.

Comment: `just because they need to redirect the user mid-page in case of an error` what about coding better scripts? Why does a well designed page fail in mid course instead of outputting an error page/message already?

Comment: Your current approach is OK. You are doing it right. Use output buffering only if you need it.

Comment: IPO is a common programming paradigma: Input, Processing, Output